# Template file is not running In Magento?

Tags: magento2, php, module, xml

Hello I am new to **Magento** & using **Magento 2.1.7**. I was learning to develop custom module. My module is working till the controller but it is not printing the data present in the template file named `blockContent.phtml`.

My Code:

> App/Code/Funky/Hello/Controller/Path/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php

namespace Funky\Hello\Controller\Path;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class HelloWorld extends Action
{
    protected $pagefactory;
    public function __construct(Context  $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->pagefactory=$pageFactory;
        Parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "testing? is working";
        return $this->pagefactory->create();

    }
}
```

> App/Code/Funky/Hello/Block/Main.php

```
<?php 
namespace Funky\Hello\Block;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Main extends Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {


    }

}
```

> App/Code/Funky/Hello/etc/frontend/route.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
        "urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="funky" frontName="funky">
            <module name="Funky_Hello"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> App/Code/Funky/Hello/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
        "urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Funky_Hello" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

> App/Code/Funky/Hello/view/frontend/layout/funky_path_helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=
        "urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Funky\Hello\Block\Main"
                   template="workin.phtml"
                   name="funky_hello_Hell"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Funky\Hello\Block\Main"
                       template="Funky_Hello::blockContent.phtml"
                       name="funky_hello_HelloWorld"/>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

> App/Code/Funky/Hello/view/frontend/layout/templates/blockContent.phtml

```
<b>Hello World!</b>

<h1>It is working or not???</h1>


<?php echo "nothing is happening why? ";?>
```

I have also created the `registration.php`.
If any one can tell me what  exactly I am doing mistake?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your *blockContent.phtml* file should be placed at *app/code/Funky/Hello/view/frontend/templates/blockContent.phtml*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the file path to

```
App/Code/Funky/Hello/view/frontend/templates/blockContent.phtml
```

instead of

```
App/Code/Funky/Hello/view/frontend/layout/templates/blockContent.phtml
```

In a layout folder there are always xml files.

Comment: layout folder does not content template files